# logging info with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, logging

Moving over from django / python, I am having a little trouble getting the rails logger to log all the information I want. I am wondering how/if the following can be achieved:

1. Having in the log format(ter) include the specific **file, function name and line** where the logging statement itself was found. Essentially the equivalent of `LOG_MSG_FORMAT = '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(filename)s:%(funcName)s(%(lineno)d) : %(message)s'` in python logger?
2. Being able to log all requests, via something similar to a django [request logging middleware](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2624/). Particularly, being able to log the **username** (if logged in) of every request.

Am I missing something obvious? or does this require (lots of) custom code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found this railtie gem that might help although I imagine it will take some "custom code" to append username to logs. See the Readme section on logging specific controllers and models.

[logging-rails railtie](https://github.com/TwP/logging-rails)

Comment: Thanks @lukewendling. I played with it and it looks nice. It even shows the controller/model which is nice, but I can't figure out how to display the file/function/line. Even after setting `trace` on. Any idea how to make this work?

Comment: Not sure but I glanced at the source to figure out how to turn off default logging by Railtie framework (don't log ActionController by default), and felt like the code was well-written and easy to understand. Perhaps you could gracefully insert __FILE__ and __LINE__ in appropriate places and submit pull request. I think that would be a nice additional feature in that gem.

Comment: Thanks again, but I'm still quite new to ruby/rails, so not sure how to do this. I've created an [issue](https://github.com/TwP/logging-rails/issues/8) so hope someone there can assist. +1 for the tip about logging-rails though.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about getting the file, function, and line number, but it's pretty easy to log from application_controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :log_user
  def log_user
    if current_user
      Rails.logger.info "Processing Request for #{current_user.name}"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks @Unixmonkey. I was hoping to embed it within the `Started GET "/" for 1.2.3.4 at 2012...` section somehow. Where I think it's the most logical place to include. Am I being too picky? Is it too much to ask?

Comment: +1 for the suggestion. Until I can work out something better, I'll probably use this method.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add a quick note in case this is useful for someone:

The [lograge gem](https://github.com/roidrage/lograge) makes rails logs much similar to django's, plus allows very neat customization, [adding parameters](https://github.com/roidrage/lograge/issues/10) such as remote ip address, current_user etc.

It also reduces verbosity of rendered layouts, which I anyway found unnecessary for production. It also plays nicely with [logging-rails railtie](https://github.com/TwP/logging-rails) mentioned by @lukewendling.

Sadly, I still couldn't find anything that shows the file/function/line number like you can easily do with django, but I guess that's just too much to ask.

Comment: Maybe this will help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12626735/adding-filename-to-rails-logger-info-messages