# Adding filename to Rails logger info messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, logging

How to add the file name and line number in Rails' log message? My current format is something like

```
[INFO : 12-09-27 10:12:30]
```

I want to change it to

```
[INFO: 12-09-27 10:12:30 application_controller.rb:35]
```

or something like this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an initializer `logger.rb` in your `config/initializers` directory and try putting this

```
class Logger::SimpleFormatter
  def call(severity, time, progname, msg)
    "[#{severity} #{time} #{caller(0).first.match(/.*:\d+/)[0]}] #{msg}\n"
  end
end
```

Should work on Ruby 1.9+

Comment: Is there anything else I need to do? This doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: The above code seems to throw a syntax error as the "caller(0)..." part is missing a "}"  Should be "[#{severity} #{time} #{caller(0).first.match(/.*:\d+/)[0]}] #{msg}\n"

Answer (score 1):

In case any one is looking for a similar solution for Rails 4. It would be:

```
class ActiveSupport::Logger::SimpleFormatter
  def call(severity, time, progname, msg)
    "[#{severity} #{time} #{caller(0).first.match(/.*:\d+/)[0]}] #{msg}\n"
  end
end
```