# How do I get Rails to display standard useful information in log statements?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

I'm new to Ruby/Rails programming and still finding my way. I have created a sample web app by following [**this**](http://www.railstutorial.org/book/demo_app) tutorial. It's working fine. It's using Ruby version 1.9.3 with Rails version 4.0.8.

However I would like to implement logging. So I inserted the following lineq into one of my controllers:

```
logger.debug "Hello! I'm a DEBUG message"
logger.info "Hello! I'm an INFO message"
```

This produced the following logs:

```
Hello! I'm a DEBUG message
Hello! I'm an INFO message
```

That's not too helpful. I want to see more details in the log output. When was this log created? What was the log level? What is the filename and line number of this log? I want to see all of that.

So I implemented the solution described [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12626735/adding-filename-to-rails-logger-info-messages) by creating a file config/initializers/logger.rb with the following contents:

```
class Logger::SimpleFormatter
  def call(severity, time, progname, msg)
    "[#{severity} #{time} #{caller(0).first.match(/.*:\d+/)[0]}] #{msg}\n"
  end
end
```

But it makes no difference. The log lines still come out bare, without any of the other essential information I'm looking for. How to fix this? Why didn't creating my logger.rb have any effect?

Comment: I recommend use autentication gems

Comment: Is very simple just ....user.authenticate(1)

Comment: This comment is not detailed enough and doesn't offer any explanation.

Comment: Have you restarted your server after adding the initializer? Initializer changes won't get automatically included by the dev server.

Comment: Yes. I restarted the rails server after I added the logger.rb file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Rails 4, the default logger for all modes (except `production`) is `ActiveSupport::Logger::SimpleFormatter`. See the documentation here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#rails-general-configuration

So, your `logger.rb` needs to be:

```
class ActiveSupport::Logger::SimpleFormatter
  def call(severity, time, progname, msg)
    "[#{severity} #{time} #{caller(0).first.match(/.*:\d+/)[0]}] #{msg}\n"
  end
end
```

Please note that this will not work in production mode. For `production` you will have to customize `Logger::Formatter` if you need to.

Comment: Thank you! However this always displays the line: /<Path To Root>/logger.rb:3. How can I change it so that it shows me the file and line number of the *calling* line.

Comment: There is no easy way to get the file information unless you write that in the message itself, like `logger.debug "SomeController:12 Message from line 12"`. I would say take out `caller(0)` part completely, since its pretty useless. Unless someone has better ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I sincerely do not understand why the logging in rails is so "bare". The default logger rails use is even better, but rails dumbs it further down.

Things I *need* in logging:

- timestamp
- severity
- preferable host-process (for joining multiple logfiles)

There are some good alternatives though, you can have a look at :

- [log4r](https://github.com/colbygk/log4r): a powerful logger, I have used it a few times, but not documented very well. Also not sure if it is still maintained.
- recently I keep using [better_logging](https://github.com/pauldowman/better_logging) which is a little less powerful, but needs less configuration to be usable out of the box, and the default serves my needs perfectly (and the custom-string option is then the finishing touch).

Comment: I also need filename and line number.
Any diagnosis why my solution didn't work?